# Adding a one-time email sign up to my start of my app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, email, xcode7

I want to add a one-time, mandatory email sign up at the beginning of my basic app. So, if the user has never used the app before, it will send them to the "sign up" page where they will enter an email, hit "submit" and then be sent to the home page of the app. If the user has already opened the app before, and therefore already entered an email, they should be sent straight to my app's home page.

How can I go about this?

Also, as an addition, how can I store all the emails that have been submitted through my app in a spreadsheet or the like?

Comment: Same question asked by someone else on yesterday and it's put on hold
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650612/how-to-implement-one-time-registration-for-email-address-in-objective-c-ios

Comment: Different question, maybe you misunderstood the meaning of my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `NSUserDefault` to store status like check in `appdelegate`'s `didfinishlaunchingwithoption` that status is `true` in user defaults then user have opened app before. If status is not true then this is firsttime for user.

So, if firsttime then set your `rootviewcontroller` as `signup` viewcontroller.
And set status to `true` in `userdefaults`.

If not first time then set `rootViewController` as `homeViewController`.

Do all your this stuff in `didfinishlaunchingwithoption` method of `appdelegate` which is got called first when app is launch.

that`s it.